# android resize animation

Tags: android, animation, drawable

Is there a way to apply a 'resize' animation as opposed to a scale animation in Android?  When using the scale animation, the image or layout being resized is stretched out, this includes the border / stroke outline that is outlines the image.  I have a box, with 2 lines around them, when the animation is applied the stroke appears to grow, this is likely due to the fact that the 'scale' animation is actually scaling the borders/strokes in addition to the drawable.  Is there any way to have the box grow, without having the stroke/border/outline appear to grow as well?  i.e. i just want to resize, but not necessarily 'rescale' the drawable.  note, my drawable is defined in xml...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the borders from the image and instead draw this border by wrapping your ImageView with a LinearLayout. Use some padding to create the borders and set the background color of your LinearLayout to apply the border appearance desired.

Answer (score -1):

The default animation tools in Android do not provide a way to perform resize animations. Your best bet is to have a TimerTask that changes the dimensions of the view on the UI thread at specified time intervals.